# Apache Cache-Control for 301 redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301, cache-control

I am trying to add s-maxage Cache-Control for 301 redirects with Apache Header Directive:

```
Header append Cache-Control s-maxage=600 "expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS} == 301"
```

But when I add this in .htaccess file nothing seems to appear. I am using Apache 2.4.6.
What do I miss?

Comment: Redirects _caused_ by - what? mod_rewrite? Could be a problem with the order in which things are processed.

Comment: You mean, the redirect is _permanent_, but only _temporary_ -ly?

Comment: I just trying to insert additional cache-control value (s-maxage) to 301 redirects for CDN's. The platform is Wordpress. The thing is that s-maxage doesn't appear at all. I just want something like this: Cache-Control s-maxage=600, max-age=21200